# What is that little triangle thingy in the corner of an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have always seen this little triangle in the corner of every Excel sheet.[image: What is it?]

What is it for? Does it have to do with alignment? I have searched Google and have no luck.

Comment: It simply indicates that square belongs to both column and row I suspect. Clicking on it on it may or may not select all the boxes.

Comment: As far as I can tell, its just a "Select All Cells" button.

Comment: Yes, it selects the entire sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to throw the [kb - select all cells on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Select-all-cells-on-a-worksheet-1a35f997-7afa-4656-bd06-c8086765fccf) official reference here as an answer.

It's also on this [kb- Select cells ranges rows or columns on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Select-cells-ranges-rows-or-columns-on-a-worksheet-23f64223-2b6b-453a-8688-248355f10fa9) -

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is a very descriptive answer. Thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

That button selects all the cells of the spreadsheet. :)

Answer (score 1):

It highlights all cells of your sheet. It can be used if you want to set every cell to a certain font style or something like that.